# Building query to select from 3 tables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Normally I know how to query and join three tables but here I can't figured it how to happen. The thing is that I have followed 3 tables:

category -> columns

```
id
name 
image
```

sub-category -> columns

```
id
table1_id
name
image
```

Sub-sub-category -> columns

```
id
table2_id
name
image
```

So image can be added only to `Category` or to `Category->Sub-Category` or to third level `Category->Sub-Category->Sub-Sub-Category`

What I'm trying to do is when I show ALL images on page to show also to which category they are added.

I've made all relations in my models but I can't figured it out how to query exactly. Currently only querying all images like

```
SubSubCategories::all();
```

Example:

I have main category(`Country`) which has sub-category (`district`) which has sub-sub-category(`city`).

`image1` is added to `Sub-Sub-Category` with name `city`. When images are listed I want to show

`images1` added to `Country->District->City`.

Can someone show me example query or maybe my relations eg. columns in tables are wrong?

This is what I've tried so far

```
    $subsubcategories = DB::table('sub_sub_category')
                ->join('sub_category', 'sub_sub_category.sub_cat_id', '=', 'sub_category.sub_cat_id')
                ->join('category', 'category.category_id', '=', 'sub_category.sub_cat_id')
                ->select('sib_sub_category.*', 'sub_category.*', 'category.*')
                ->get();
```

Then in my view

```
{{ $subsubcategory->sub_category->sub_cat_name }} > {{ $subsubcategory->sub_sub_cat_name }}
```

error

> Undefined property: stdClass::$sub_category

Answer (score 2):

```
$subsubcategories = DB::table('category')
            ->join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'sub_category.table1_id')
            ->join('sub_category', 'sub_category.id', '=', 'sub_sub_category.table2_id')
            ->select('category.*', 'sub_category.*', 'sub_sub_category.*')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are almost there. Just remove the `sub_category` from the view and will work.

```
{{ $subsubcategory->sub_cat_name }} > {{ $subsubcategory->sub_sub_cat_name }}
```

This is happen because your array currently is looks like

```
object(stdClass) {
  ["id"]=> int(1)
  ["table2_id"]=> int(1)
  ["table1_id"]=> int(1)

  ...
  // all other columns
}
```

So actually they belongs to $subsubcategory and no need to bring `sub_category` and `category` in the view. Just display them in your `$subsubcategory`.